# read_csv() with messy quotation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV-file I want to read into a pandas df, but encounter some troubles.

The CSV-file (file.csv) has a structure as following:

```
header1, header2, header3
"abc, \" hello \" ", 0, "aaa"
"abc, \", 0, "aaa"
```

I want the following output:

```
header1, header2, header3
"abc, hello", 0, aaa
abc, 0, aaa
```

If I apply `pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, escapechar = "\\")` I get the following output:

```
           header1   header2  header3
0  abc, " hello "        0.0    "aaa"
1   abc ", 0, aaa"       NaN      NaN
```

I actually don't care about special characters, comma's etc. I only want the correct values to be in the correct columns as illustrated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with `pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, escapechar = "\\")`. Can you add to your question, a more complete example, the code used and the full traceback error ?

Comment: @Timeless Thanks for your feedback. The question is updated.

Answer (score 2):

> **I actually don't care about special characters, comma's etc**. I only
> want the correct values to be in the correct columns as illustrated.

Here is a *proposition* with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
from io import StringIO

s = """header1, header2, header3
"abc, \" hello \" ", 0, "aaa"
"abc, \", 0, "aaa"""
​
df = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(s)) # <- put here your .csv-pathfile
          .astype(str) # <- to cast all the cols as str for cleaning
          .replace({'[",]*': "", "\s+": " ", "\s*$": ""}, regex=True)
          .rename(columns=str.strip)
          .infer_objects()
     )
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

     header1 header2 header3
0  abc hello       0     aaa
1        abc       0     aaa
```

Comment: Could you by any chance briefly explain the regex part?

Comment: `df.replace` accepts a dictionnary to replace multiple substrings. Here, we first get rid of special characters, then replace extra whitespaces with a single whitespace and finally remove any trailing whitespaces. You can comment (`#`) the line when we call `df.replace` to see the difference.